# SAP HANA : Input parameter filter value '*' issue

Tags: hana

I want to introduce a problem that we are facing in our project regarding Input parameter filtering issue.

Problem:

We have 5 input parameters in our SAP HANA view with default value ‘*’ to have the possibilities to select all values.

Now when we want to select data from this HANA view into our table function using script we pass input parameter values using “PLACEHOLDER” statement but for this statement ‘*’ is not working( it returns no result).

More important point is this that if I hard code value as ‘*’, it is showing the data correctly but if I use variable (that holds ‘*’ value), it shows me no data.
For example:

- For plant (`WERKS`) filter, if I put constant ‘*’, it is giving me all data
- For plant (`WERKS`) filter, if I put use a variable (`ZIN_WERKS`) that have ‘*’ value passed from input screen of final view, it is giving me no data.

I checked that variable is correctly filled with ‘*’ value but still no data that we are not able to understand.

Additional question, do we always give default value as ‘*’ for input parameters because if it is blank or empty, it always filter on blank values and value help could also not be generated?

Have you ever encounter these issues because it seems very basic points in SAP HANA…?
We would really appreciate for any help/hint regarding these issues…

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a question that has been asked already. The point here is that you seem to want to mimic the selection behaviour from SAP Netweaver based applications in your HANA models.
One difference to consider here is that the placeholder character on SQL databases like HANA is not `*` but `%`.
Also, the placeholder search only works when your model uses the `LIKE` comparison, but not with `=` (equal) or `>`, `<`, or any other combination of range queries.

In short: if you want to have this specific behaviour just like in SAP Netweaver, you will have to build your own scripted view and explicitly test for which parameters had been provided and which are "INITIAL".
One useful feature for this scenario is the `APPLY_FILTER()` function in SQLScript, that allows to apply dynamic filters in information models.
More on that can be found in the modelling guide.